# How to extract data from dynamic collapsing table with hidden elements using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I try to scrape these 20 classifications from `https://patents.google.com/patent/JP2009517369A/en?oq=JP2009517369`, from which the first is displayed and the others are hidden in an expandable section.

I already tried to get the first visible one with

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style-scope classification-tree' and not(@hidden)]/state-modifier[@class='code style-scope classification-tree']/a[@class='style-scope state-modifier']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML")
```

However, it raises an exception and I don't know why. So I figured that scraping the whole table would be easier but most of the elements are folded.

Is there any approach on how to scrape dynamic hidden tables?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: The code you have tried its working here.What is your expected output could you post?

Comment: Oh really! It's supposed to scrape the text "C07C311/51"

Comment: Yes it is printed that value. What value are you getting?

Comment: Ah now it is printing the value. But why am I getting timeoutExceptions in this line after awhile?

Answer (score 0):

The First two options should print the value `C07C311/51`

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style-scope classification-tree' and not(@hidden)]/state-modifier[@class='code style-scope classification-tree']/a[@class='style-scope state-modifier']"))).text)
```

OR

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style-scope classification-tree' and not(@hidden)]/state-modifier[@class='code style-scope classification-tree']/a[@class='style-scope state-modifier']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

However if you do not get the expected value try the last one.this should print any hidden content.

```
print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='style-scope classification-tree' and not(@hidden)]/state-modifier[@class='code style-scope classification-tree']/a[@class='style-scope state-modifier']"))).get_attribute("textContent"))
```